# mysql 12 hr to 24 hr time conversion

Tags: mysql

How can we convert the time in AM/PM to 24-hrs format. For eg. (1:30 PM) should be converted to (13:30).

Comment: Are you storing it as a string (e.g. VARCHAR)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dates / Times are stored in mysql the same way regardless of how they are formatted.

I believe what you want to do is retrieve the date in a specified format.

The DATE_FORMAT() will do this for you.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

%r and %T are 12 hour and 24 hour time formats respectively.

Comment: I tried giving:
    select time_format('01:56:39 PM','%T') 
But it's returning same 01:56:39 PM and giving a warring as "Truncated incorrect time value: '01:56:39 PM' "

Comment: The value you are passing in to time_format is still a string, and mysql expects to do it's work on a date value.  Try converting to a date first, like

select time_format(str_to_date('01:56:39 PM','%r'),'%T');

Comment: Hi, Can you please update your comment to your answer..bcoz the comment is what helped.. the answer to my query and possibly the user's was the `str_to_date` method... Thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

Hi all I think this will help you

```
select STR_TO_DATE('8:25 PM', '%l:%i %p' )
```

the result will be

```
>20:25:00
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use MySQL's DATE_FORMAT http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
Table: records
Column date: Type date,
Column hours: Type string (am/pm format)


SELECT
date,
hours,
CONCAT(date, ' ', IF(LOCATE('pm',hours) > 0, ADDTIME(TIME(REPLACE(hours, ' pm','')), '12:00:00'),  TIME(REPLACE(hours, ' am',''))))
FROM records
```

Comment: The above converts `12:30pm` to `24:30` just fyi

Answer (score 1):

1:=> print( date("H:i:s", strtotime("1:30 pm")) );

output: 13:30:00