# PHP Sum total hours with conditions continued

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, sum, where-clause

This is a continuation of my question from [PHP Sum a value in while loop, but with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24601898/php-sum-a-value-in-while-loop-but-with-conditions/24601964#24601964)

I have two tables to be joined, 1 is user and 1 is attendance.
column isOt in table attendance is to indicate that the user was granted overtime from superior.

```
TABLE : attendance
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
id   userId   totalHours  isOt  dateRecorded
1    1        0745        0     02-06-2014
2    3        0845        1     07-06-2014
3    1        0945        1     12-06-2014

TABLE : user
+++++++++++++++++++++++
id   name  departmentId
1    John  2
2    Sean  2
3    Allan 2
```

With the help of many people, solution provided with this query indeed working in helping me to SUM totalHours for each user

But I made some additional query line like below:

```
$query = "SELECT u.employeeName, u.id, a.isOt, a.dateRecorded,
SUM((CAST(totalHours AS UNSIGNED) % 100)/60 + FLOOR(CAST(totalHours AS UNSIGNED)/100))  grandTotal FROM user u RIGHT JOIN attendance a
ON u.id = a.userId
WHERE u.departmentId = 2
GROUP BY u.id HAVING dateRecorded >= '01-06-2014' <= '31-06-2014'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
   print $row['id'] . ' ' . $row['grandTotal'];
}
```

The above query successfully shows two rows of output like how I wanted
But now there's another tricky challenge for beginner like me WHERE

I need to get total overtime by let say

```
(if isOt == 1)
{
minus totalHours with 0800 (min working time)
and them sum up the balance and echo it for each user
}
```

Any help is appreciated, I am still beginner and trying to learn as much I could.
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Looks to me like you're trying to get  people here to write your code for you, bit by bit. Where's __your__ attempt at this new problem?

Comment: Hi Mike, i understand you might think I didn't trying
But actually i did and stuck within, inside the loop i added the below query to find the sum but not successful

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE userId = $id"
               $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$query2);
          while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) 
          $totalOt = 0;
          {
           if ($row2['isOt']==1)
           {
            $totalOt += $row['totalHours']-'0800';
            echo $totalOt;
           }
           else
           {
           }
           
          }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a case when statement

```
SELECT u.employeeName, 
       u.id, 
       a.isOt, 
       a.dateRecorded,
       Case When a.totalHours > 0800 Then 0800 Else totalHours End As NormalHours
       Case When a.totalHours > 0800 Then totalHours - 0800 Else 0 End As OTHours
FROM user u RIGHT JOIN 
     attendance a
ON u.id = a.userId
WHERE u.departmentId = 2
GROUP BY u.id 
HAVING dateRecorded >= '01-06-2014' <= '31-06-2014'
```

Assuming totalHours is stored in a number format.

Comment: is it okay with this CASE?
Case When a.isOt = 1 Then SUM(totalHours - 0800) Else 0 End As otTotal

Comment: lgtm, try it and lemme know

Comment: It works on 1 user only, but it didn't with the other user
an id has 0 and another have the correct otTotal

Comment: Sum(Case When a.isOT = 1 Then totalHours - 0800 Else 0 End) As otTotal

Comment: user1594030 : absolute genius, my mistake to place the SUM inside the case and you nailed it :)

i appreciate your help and time and may your journey of life be as remarkable