# phpMyAdmin datetime only accept 12 hour format

Tags: php, sql, datetime

In my php code I insert `datetime` to my table like this:

**php code:**

```
$doinmysql = "INSERT INTO my_table (id,order_date) VALUES('0','date("Y-m-d H:i:s")')";
mysql_query($doinmysql);
```

if I `echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` I get `"2015-08-27 15:48:19"` - a time in 24 hour format, but in the db u have: `"2015-08-27 03:48:19"`- a time in 12 hour format.

any idea how I can solve this?

thanks!!!

edit:
if i run the same query in sql tab in phpmyadmin the date is insert in 24 hour format, still from my php to db he change.

Comment: Hi i think this link may help you.. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986058/mysql-12-hr-to-24-hr-time-conversion

Comment: still after i used DATE_FORMAT same problem!

Comment: Could you make a http://sqlfiddle.com with your schema and full query (with values) to make this easier for myself and others to diagnose? thanks.

Comment: If I try `$doinmysql = "INSERT INTO my_table (id,order_date) VALUES('0','date("Y-m-d H:i:s")')";` I get `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'Y' (T_STRING)`. Can you post the exact code that you're running? I suspect you may be trying to use the MySQL `DATE()` function using a PHP date format.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your data/time format in db using:

```
SET GLOBAL datetime_format ='%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s';
SET GLOBAL time_format ='%H:%i:%s';
```

before you can also check which format you use:

```
show variables like 'date%format';
```

Comment: in the config file: datetime_format ='%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'; and time_format ='%H:%i:%s';

Comment: Ok this is configuration, could you query your database with `show variables like 'date%format';` and check what is there to make 100% sure?

Comment: tomasz thanks the query return : date_format : %Y-%m-%d,datetime_format:%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s

Comment: Try to modify your query into:
`INSERT INTO my_table (id,order_date) VALUES('0',NOW())"`

Answer (score 0):

use mysql `DATE_FORMAT` function

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_date,'%Y-%m-%d %r'), order_date FROM my_table
```

[for more about DATE_FORMAT function - read more](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

Comment: still after i used DATE_FORMAT same problem!

Comment: did you run the above query in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: yes the answer is : date_format : %Y-%m-%d,datetime_format:%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s